# ASP.NET Core 3 logging to output window

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core 3 WEB API project and I want to trace using stopwatch the time execution of some method sending the result to the output window of Visual Studio 2019 by using Debub.WriteLine(...)

The issue is that this output window is bombed with hundreds of lines of information per seconds by .NET Core framework itself. They are not errors, warning.

I've tried to set to **Warning** or **None** the log level in the appsettings.json but nothing has changed.

```
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "None",
      "Microsoft": "None",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "None"
    }
  },
```

I've tried to disable by going to "TOOLS --> Options --> Projects and Solutions --> Web Projects" and checking "Disable local Application Insights for Asp.Net Core web projects." and nothing has changed.

Is there a way to disable all that trash sent to the output window?

[image]

*** UPDATE ***
I've tried also to add the following:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).ConfigureLogging(config =>
    {
        config.ClearProviders();
    })
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        });
```

and nothing has changed.

****** UPDATE 2 ******
Tried to modify the appsettings.development.json by setting everything to None and then by setting what suggested by Fei Han, but nothing changes again:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to disable all that trash sent to the output window?

You can try to add following code in `appsettings.Development.json` file to set LogLevel
of `Microsoft` to `None` for [Debug](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#debug) provider.

```
{
  "Logging": {
    //...
    //code for other provider
    //...

    "Debug": { //Debug provider
      "IncludeScopes": true,
      "LogLevel": {
        "Microsoft": "None"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Giox, above code works well for me. You can try to add `"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "None"` for Debug provider then check if it works well.

Comment: Thanks Fei, unfortunately it doesn't work for me. I've tried to add "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "None" and/or "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database": "None" and "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command": "None"... nothing changes. They are completely ignored

Comment: If possible, you can share the complete code (hidden account and pwd etc sensitive data) of `appsettings.json` and 
 `appsettings.Development.json`, so that we can help troubleshoot the issue better.

Comment: Thanks, the code for appsettings files are the one I've published in the question, there is nothing else in them.